What constitutes "fault of the buyer"?
I have a contract to sell my house that is contingent on the buyer selling their home. A common enough occurrence.

If Buyer does not close on the sale of Buyer’s property, through no
fault of Buyer, on or before ______ of ______, then this Sale Contract
shall terminate with earnest money to be returned to Buyer, subject
to paragraph 12 of the Sale Contract.

What constitutes "fault of Buyer"? In this case, their house is over-priced and they have failed to even counter after receiving an offer they considered too low.
I recognize this is very quickly going to turn in to "call your own lawyer", but I'm kinda trying to determine whether it even makes sense to make that call yet.
Edit: Paragraph 12 governs how the Escrow company handles returning the money or handles a dispute, not conditions on "fault of Buyer".
Edit: By request, here is the Remedies section of the contract.

If either party defaults in the performance of any obligation of this
contract, the party claiming a default shall notify the other party in
writing of the nature of the default and his election of remedy. The
notifying party may, but is not required to, provide the defaulting
party with a deadline for curing the default. If the default is by
Buyer, Seller may either accept the earnest money as liquidated
damages and release Buyer from the contract (in lieu of making any
claim in court), or may pursue any remedy at law or in equity. If
Seller accepts the earnest money, it shall be divided as follows:
expenses of broker and Seller in this transaction will be reimbursed,
and balance to go one-half to Seller, and one-half divided equally
between listing broker and selling broker (if working as subagent of
Seller) in lieu of commission on this contract. If the default is by
Seller, Buyer may either release Seller from liability upon Seller’s
release of the earnest money and reimbursement to Buyer for all direct
costs and expenses, as specified in Buyer’s notice of default (in lieu
of making any claim in court), or may pursue any remedy at law and in
equity, including enforcement of sale.
Buyer’s release of Seller does not relieve Seller of his liability to
brokers under the listing contract. In the event of litigation between
the parties, the prevailing party shall recover, in addition to
damages or equitable relief, the cost of litigation including
reasonable attorney’s fee. This provision shall survive Closing and
delivery of Seller’s deed to Buyer.


Would editing this question to be about what the standard for "fault of the buyer" and avoiding references to my specific contract or situation allow this question to be re-opened?

"Fault of the buyer" in this case, would normally mean that the buyer breached the contract to sell their home, or otherwise actively undermined the sale of their home (e.g. by colluding with a buyer of their home to prevent the deal from going through until after they are released from their contract with you).
Normally, a listing price at the high end of what is reasonable would not constitute "fault of the buyer."
